# Using Blog Overflow design elements on an off-site blog

Tags: support, design, blog, licensing, blog-overflow

As mentioned in [this question](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285478/blogoverflow-text-overflow), we (the SF/F community) are expecting that Blog Overflow will be shutting down at some point in the future. Given that we actually use our blog on a regular basis, we decided to get a jump on migrating it off-site to minimize the downtime.

I [asked](//meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10274/look-and-feel-of-the-new-blog) on our meta what people wanted in terms of look/feel for the blog, and the consensus was that we liked the design that was put together for our current blog, and we'd like to reuse as much of it as possible.

From what I've been told ([here](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285478/blogoverflow-text-overflow#comment926761_285478) and [here](//meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10274/look-and-feel-of-the-new-blog#comment30365_10274)), it seems like Stack Exchange has no issue with us reusing the design elements, and might be able to help us out. Our off-site blog is actually a hosted WordPress site, so I'm really hoping that we can just extract the "theme" from the scifi.blogoverflow site and load it up there, but at the very least I wanted to get "official" confirmation that we can take the images and CSS and copy them over.

Who can help us out with this transition, and what do they need from us?

Comment: It looks like you solved this, as the SF&F blog has the same look & feel and is no longer on Blog Overflow.

Comment: yeah, SE reached out to us after this post and provided us the Wordpress theme they used.